# How can I write a SQL JOIN where zip codes do not match in length?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to join two data tables on several fields in Access. The problem is that the zip code is nine digits sometimes in one table and consistently five digits in the other.

My basic query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2 
INNER JOIN tbl2
  ON (tbl1.last_name=tbl2.last_name) AND (tbl1.zip=tbl2.zip);
```

How can I write this in Access SQL where it will match just the first five digits of the zip code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left()` function

Assuming tbl1.zip is 9 digits

```
Select * From tbl2 
INNER JOIN tbl1 
  ON (tbl1.last_name=tbl2.last_name) AND (left(tbl1.zip,5)=tbl2.zip);
```

Comment: +1 INNER JOIN tbl1 and bearing in mind that this must be created in SQL view of MS Access.